# ttk.Spinbox always highlights value

Tags: python-3.x, select, tkinter, ttk, spinbox

I realised that the `ttk.Spinbox` always seems to highlight the new value that got chosen via up or down button. Is there a way to avoid this functionality? It's possible to set `selectbackground=<background color>, selectforeground=<foreground color>` in Style but that just hides the problem.

- OS: Windows 10 Home
- Tcl/Tk: 8.6
- Python: 3.7.3

Reproducable example:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Spinbox, Style

root = Tk()
spinbox = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10)
spinbox.pack(expand=True)

### How to hide it
style = Style(root)
style.configure('TSpinbox',
                selectbackground=style.configure('TSpinbox', 'background'), #set selectforeground to foreground
                selectforeground=style.configure('TSpinbox', 'foreground')) #set selectbackground to background
###

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what is the problem of _'hides the problem'_?

Comment: That the values will still be selected. So the user could accidentially delete/copy/whatever it.

Comment: Then set the spinbox to readonly mode: `spinbox = Spinbox(..., state='readonly')`.

Comment: Tried that already but it still got selected.